# Summarise value from two table in R

Tags: r

I have two tables as follows:

```
A<-data.frame("Task"=c("a","b","c","d","e"),"FC"=(c(100,120,200,300,400)))
B<-data.frame("Task"=c("a","b","c"),"FC"=(c(20,50,30)))

  Task  FC
1    a 100
2    b 120
3    c 200
4    d 300
5    e 400
  Task FC
1    a 20
2    b 50
3    c 30
```

How can I create `table C` with output is summarise of coresposing `Task` from `A` and `B`?

```
  Task  FC
1    a 120
2    b 170
3    c 230
```

Comment: What exactly is this summary value? Looks like a sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

merge dfs

```
df=merge(A,B,by="Task",all=F)
```

summarise the data

```
df$sum=apply(df[,2:3],1,sum)#sum, sd, min, max or ...

> df
  Task FC.x FC.y sum
1    a  100   20 120
2    b  120   50 170
3    c  200   30 230
```